# SQLAlchemy: Using delete/update with a join query

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Using Flask-SQLAlchemy, I would like to delete rows in table `Questions` based on the values of another table which is linked to table `Topic` which then is linked to table `Subject` with foreign keys. I tried this query:

```
db.session.query(Questions).join(Topic)join(Subject).filter(Subject.account_id==current_user.id).delete()
```

However, I receive an error:

```
InvalidRequestError: Can't call Query.update() or Query.delete() when join(), outerjoin(), select_from(), or from_self() has been called
```

So from this I suppose I cannot use `.delete()` with `.join()`

Is there a workaround for this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to use join for your query, you may done it somehow like

```
db.session.query(Post).filter(Post.user_id==current_user.id).delete()
```

Assuming your Post have a user_id column.

Join tables would not know which table to delete, Post or User, because it actually have a convoluted middle table constructed, and query from it.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without referring to the `user_id` column in posts?  The example I used is just a common analogy for my actual problem.

Comment: how do you link Post with User, shouldn't Post have a column referred to User?

Comment: I have updated the question to fit my issue, I don't think I was clear sorry. would like to delete every question which links to a row in topic which links to a row in subject which has a matching account_id.

Answer (score 2):

Based on similar discussion in [Update joined table via SQLAlchemy ORM using session.query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153823/update-joined-table-via-sqlalchemy-orm-using-session-query) I was able to figure out a workaround if you're using ORM instead of Core. Break the joins out into a separate cte/subquery, which return the ids for the rows you want to update.

```
question_joins = db.session.query(Question).join(Topic)join(Subject)
question_filter  = question_joins.filter(Subject.account_id==current_user.id)
question_id_subquery = question_filter.with_entities(Question.id).subquery()

db.session.query(Question).filter(Question.id.in_(question_id_subquery)).delete()
```