# Update joined table via SQLAlchemy ORM using session.query

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Working with MySQL, I'd like to generate this SQL:

```
UPDATE tableA
INNER JOIN tableB
ON tableA.some_id = tableB.some_id
SET tableA.foo = 1
WHERE tableB.bar IN ('baz','baaz')
```

This is my SQLAlchemy query:

```
session.query(tableA).join(tableB, tableA.some_id == tableB.some_id) \
                     .filter(tableB.bar.in_(['baz','baaz']))\
                     .update({tableA.foo: 1})
```

But the SQL it generates is this (a multi-table update, with no join condition, which is not what I want):

```
UPDATE tableA, tableB 
SET tableA.foo = 1
WHERE tableB.bar IN ('baz','baaz')
```

I've tried changing the .join into another .filter to specify the join condition, that didn't solve the problem.
How do I force this simple update statement to do the proper join?

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I have something almost identical and I'm struggling

Comment: Had to move on with a workaround (two queries instead of one).  Upvote the question if you're struggling with the same, maybe someone will see it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of version 0.7.4 [sqlalchemy.sql.expression.update](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/dml.html?highlight=sqlalchemy%20expression%20update#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.update) does allow you to refer to multiple tables in the WHERE clause. With this, you could build and execute an expression like:

```
users.update().values(name='ed').where(
        users.c.name==select([addresses.c.email_address]).\
                    where(addresses.c.user_id==users.c.id).\
                    as_scalar()
        )
```

*(example straight from the link above)*

The problem ValAyal is having is actually because `Query.join()` is not supported with `Query.update()`. Unfortunately, until 0.9.1 this was silently generating queries like the one ValAyal shared above. The [changelog notes for 0.9.1](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/changelog_09.html#change-af136f4c0f377ed2650ebb765f409144) notes that the behavior was modified to emit a warning:

> [orm] [bug] Query doesn’t support joins, subselects, or special FROM
>   clauses when using the Query.update() or Query.delete() methods;
>   instead of silently ignoring these fields if methods like Query.join()
>   or Query.select_from() has been called, a warning is emitted. As of
>   1.0.0b5 this will raise an error.
>
> References: [#3349](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/ticket/3349)

We actually ran into this where I work just this evening and found that our code is, in fact, emitting the following warning (which says it will an error in 1.0):

```
SAWarning: Can't call Query.update() or Query.delete() when join(), outerjoin(), select_from(), or from_self() has been called.  This will be an exception in 1.0
  self._validate_query_state()
```

In our case, we opted to convert the update into a select and an update to one table.

Comment: Note that the example here is not a multi table update, but the standard SQL way to refer to multiple tables using a sub query.

Answer (score 10):

I think I had exactly the same problem. Here is my solution:

```
query = update(Model).values(field=123)
query = query.where(Model.parent_model_id == ParentModel.id)
query = query.where(ParentModel.grand_parent_id == GrandParentModel.id)
query = query.where(GrandParentModel.name == 'foobar')
session.execute(query)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for sqlite, but probably does for other DB backends

Comment: Years later (2023), this is working for me while using an sqlite database.