# How to update a table with SQLAlchemy based on a condition on another table. .Join() doesn't work with .Update()

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy as an ORM in a python fastapi project. I have an endpoint that is updating a few rows in a table. However, I only want those rows to be updated if a field in a joined table is set to false.

Unfortunately, .Join() is not supported for the .Update method.

My code looks like this:

```
@Session
async def update_special_user_id(session: AsyncSession, old_user_id: str, user_id: str):
    await session.execute(
        update(SpecialUsers)
        .join(Users)
        .where(Users.is_claimed.is_(False))
        .where(SpecialUsers.user_id == old_user_id)
        .values({"user_id": user_id})
    )
```

`SpecialUsers` here joins with a FK relationship to `Users`. I only want the user_id in SpecialUsers to update if the Users record has the field `is_claimed == False`

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153823/update-joined-table-via-sqlalchemy-orm-using-session-query) but to no avail. Most posts I've found about SQLAlchemy are really old and things changed in 1.0.

Any ideas anyone?

My backend is running postgres

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this would be to create a `SELECT` for the ids that should be updated, and use it as the left hand side of an `IN` clause in the `UPDATE`.

This is synchronous code, but the async version should be the same.

```py
with Session() as s, s.begin():
    selectable = (
        sa.select(SpecialUsers.id)
        .join(Users)
        .where(Users.is_claimed.is_(False))
        .where(SpecialUsers.user_id == old_user_id)
    )
    s.execute(
        sa.update(SpecialUsers)
        .where(SpecialUsers.id.in_(selectable))
        .values({'user_id': user_id})
        .execution_options(synchronize_session='fetch')
    )
```

The `synchronize_session` execution option is discussed [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#selecting-a-synchronization-strategy).