# How do I update multiple rows when applying a left join on a model query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In this little card scanning app demo I'm making while learning SQLAlchemy, I'm attempting to make any card(s) assigned to a user inactive after the user is made inactive. I'm struggling to write a query that will update the access card status value with a left join in the mix. Here's what I have now:

```
# if user does not have active status, update any assigned card(s) status to inactive
if user.status != UserStatusEnum.ACTIVE:
    db.session.query(AccessCard) \
        .join(
            UserAccessCard,
            UserAccessCard.access_card_id == AccessCard.id,
            isouter=True
        ) \
        .update(status=AccessCardStatusEnum.INACTIVE) \
        .where(UserAccessCard.assigned_to_user_id == user.id)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Query.update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'status'
```

This is specific to `AccessCard.status`. When entering that:

```
...
.update(AccessCard.status=AccessCardStatusEnum.INACTIVE)
...
```

I get a new error:

```
    .update(AccessCard.status=AccessCardStatusEnum.INACTIVE) \
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

I feel like I'm super close. The join is tripping me up though. I can see querying the cards, then updating individually in a loop as one option. Yet, that seems like more steps than needed.

How should I make this joined update query happen?

Comment: Have you tried [passing it as a dict](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.update)?

Comment: Good thoughts. I can dig more into this, yet I get this error: `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't call Query.update() or Query.delete() when join(), outerjoin(), select_from(), or from_self() has been called` when: `{AccessCard.status: AccessCardStatusEnum.INACTIVE}`. That's a new clue though I can investigate. Perhaps my order of operations is off with join.

Comment: Checking to see if this might work on my next break: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35597101/1279000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing [this non-selected answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35597101/1279000), I was able to rework my query with success:

```
...
from sqlalchemy import update
...

query = update(AccessCard).values(
        status=AccessCardStatusEnum.INACTIVE
    ) \
    .where(UserAccessCard.access_card_id == AccessCard.id) \
    .where(UserAccessCard.assigned_to_user_id == user.id)
db.session.execute(query)
```